# Why a scala test assertion on an object's val throws NullPointerException?

Tags: scala, scalatest

While testing Scala code, I've run into a strange NPE while asserting on a value from an object.

Here is the minimal code to reproduce the issue:

**main/scala/Playground.scala:**

```scala
object Playground extends App {
  val greeting = "Hello Scala"
  println(greeting)
}
```

**test/scala/PlaygroundSpec.scala:**

```scala
import org.scalatest.wordspec._

class PlaygroundSpec extends AnyWordSpec {
  "The playground code" should {
    "say hello" in {
      assert(Playground.greeting.contains("Hello")) // Throws NPE because greeting is null. How???
    }
  }
}
```

The sample program run just fine and prints "hello Scala", but the test throws a NullPointerException on the assertion line, because `greeting` is `null`.

**How could `greeting` be `null` if it is initialized with a string constant?**

> **Note:** Adding `lazy` to the `val` declaration makes it work and the test passes.

Comment: `App`  does some fancy things like moving all the body of the object into a lazy val and delying its initialization. just use a normal `main` method _(in any case **Scala 3** will remove it)_ or move everything you want to test outside the `App` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala 2 `App` extends [`DelayedInit`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/DelayedInit.html), so compiler magically rewrites initialisation code such that the initialisation of fields is moved to `delayedInit` method, for example,

```
object Playground extends App {
  val greeting = "Hello Scala"
  println(greeting)
}
```

becomes something like

```
object Playground extends App {
  private var greeting: String = null
  def greeting(): String = greeting

  def delayedInit(): Unit = {   
    greeting = "Hello Scala"
    println(greeting()) 
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    // indirectly call delayedInit
    ...
  }
}
```

Now we can see

```
assert(Playground.greeting.contains("Hello"))
```

becomes

```
assert(null.contains("Hello"))
```

as `delayedInit` method did not get called. To prove the point observe how the following works

```
Playground.main(Array.empty) // delayedInit gets indirectly called
assert(Playground.greeting.contains("Hello")) // ok
```

> Adding lazy to the val declaration makes it work and the test passes.

This works because `lazy val greeting` effectively turns the field into a method which moves it out of the initialisation code so it does not become part of `delayedInit`.

Clearly this is confusing so Scala 3 [Dropped: Delayedinit](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/delayed-init.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could define `Playground` this way:

```scala
object Playground /*extends App*/ {
  val greeting = "Hello Scala"
  println(greeting)
}
```

Or you could define `greeting` this way:

```scala
object Playground extends App {
  lazy val greeting = "Hello Scala"
  println(greeting)
}
```

The explanation for this odd behavior of Scala 2.x is that `App` features lazy loading. This has been problematic in the past for many others. Scala 3 will change that.

For Scala 2, your safest option is to move your object references outside the body of `App`, for example:

```scala
class Playground {
  val greeting = "Hello Scala"
  println(greeting)
}

object Playground extends App {
  new Playground
}
```