# Property of an object extending App has null value when accessed in REPL

Tags: scala, sbt

**My question is how do I access DownloadFiles.fileURLList property in sbt console (Scala REPL)?**

I created a SBT Scala project and have this code at `src/main/scala/DownloadFiles.scala`

```scala
    import sys.process._
    import biz.neumann.url.NiceURLCodecs._
    import java.net._
    import java.io._

    object DownloadFiles extends App {
        val fileURLList = Array(
            "https://www.example.com/file1.txt",
            "https://www.example.com/file2.txt",
            "https://www.example.com/file3.txt"
        )

        fileURLList.foreach(url => {
            val fileName = "downloaded-files/" + new File(new URI(url).getPath).getName;
            println(url.decode.encode + ": " + fileName)
            new URL(url.decode.encode) #> new File(fileName) !!
        })
    }
```

I opened Scala REPL by using `sbt console` and when I access fileURLList property of DownloadFiles object I get null value (unevaluated) as shown below.

> scala> DownloadFiles.fileURLList

> res0: Array[String] = null

What I instead need is evaluated value of the property of that object.

Here's the `build.sbt` if it helps:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
name := "image-downloader"
organization := "in.bhargav.inc"
version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "biz.neumann" % "nice-url-encode-decode_2.12" % "1.5"
```

Comment: This is a consequence of `Hello` extending `App` which indirectly extends `DalayedInit` which changes the initialisation semantics. Try declaring `fileURLList` as `lazy`, or call `DownloadedFiles.main(Array.emtpy)` before calling `fileURLList`. See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896016/why-a-scala-test-assertion-on-an-objects-val-throws-nullpointerexception

Comment: @MarioGalic thanks! That was it. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a consequence of `Hello` extending `App` which indirectly extends [`DalayedInit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66902230/5205022) which changes the initialisation semantics:

```
@nowarn("""cat=deprecation&origin=scala\.DelayedInit""")
trait App extends DelayedInit
```

Quick fix is to make `fileURLList` lazy

```
➜ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_282).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> object DownloadFiles extends App {
     |   val fileURLList = Array("https://www.example.com/file1.txt")
     | }
object DownloadFiles

scala> DownloadFiles.fileURLList
val res1: Array[String] = null

scala> object DownloadFiles extends App {
     |   lazy val fileURLList = Array("https://www.example.com/file1.txt")
     | }
object DownloadFiles

scala> DownloadFiles.fileURLList
val res2: Array[String] = Array(https://www.example.com/file1.txt)
```

This behaviour changed in [Scala 3](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/main-functions.html) which drops `DelayedInit` semantics

```
➜ scala3-repl 
scala> object DownloadFiles extends App {
     |   val fileURLList = Array("https://www.example.com/file1.txt")
     | }
// defined object DownloadFiles

scala> DownloadFiles.fileURLList                                                                                                            
val res0: Array[String] = Array(https://www.example.com/file1.txt)
```

> The previous functionality of App, which relied on the "magic"
> DelayedInit trait, is no longer available. App still exists in limited
> form for now, but it does not support command line arguments and will
> be **deprecated** in the future. If programs need to cross-build between
> Scala 2 and Scala 3, it is recommended to use an explicit main method
> with an Array[String] argument instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your code uses a variable called fileURLList.  The second part of your code and your SBT command use imageURLList. imageURLList is never declared as a variable, therefore it is null.  Find and replace your code from fileURLList to imageURLList and I bet it will do what you were expecting.

I am a little surprised you didn't get other errors though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistakes. It happened because I was modifying the code for SO. I fixed it now but the issue is the same. So the problem, as pointed as a comment under the question is the actual reason and I can confirm as I checked the same with Scala Reddit group.